# Help with Mathematica Documentation Installation Error

Tags: documentation

I've encountered an error while installing the documentation for Mathematica, as displayed in the image below. Although the file that the software is asking for is clearly visible and unrestricted, the error persists. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

I was considering reinstalling Mathematica to include the local documentation, but the thought of having to reconfigure the MaTeX package settings has deterred me from doing so.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I see the word `and` in the folder name in the last image?

Comment: @Syed Ah, I didn't realize that. You're correct, I just noticed that there are two folders, with one having an additional "and" in its name. Let me try again.

Comment: Unfortunately the error happens again.

Comment: The fact that it reads the first file and generates an error on the second one in the set is perhaps where the mystery lies. Try temporarily renaming the first file in each of the folders one at a time to see if there is a difference in the outcome.

Comment: @Syed Yes, I did try that, but the error persists. Therefore, I have decided to reinstall it, and I am in the process of doing so now.

Comment: @Syed I reinstalled it, and it's working now. Interestingly, contrary to my belief, all my packages and license were automatically kept from the previous installation, which I didn't know.